# PDF form to HTML conversion in angular 2?

Tags: node.js, angular

In my application I am uploading a PDF file after uploading, I should display the information present in PDF file to a HTML form we are using angular 2 for frontend and node js for backend. Can any one help me with this.

Please remember PDF to HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing. Convert your pdf to a JSON. Use [pdf2json](https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json).

> pdf2json is a node.js module that parses and converts PDF from binary to json format, it's built with pdf.js and extends it with
>   interactive form elements and text content parsing outside browser.
>   The goal is to enable server side PDF parsing with interactive form
>   elements when wrapped in web service, and also enable parsing local
>   PDF to json file when using as a command line utility.
>
> perform ***npm install pdf2json***

Create an empty JSON whose key values will be the main headings from the pdf like a customer, age etc. Its values are obtained from the uploaded pdf.
Using this JSON values fill your form, on saving the form using, node.js save it to your DB. Is this what you want?

Comment: I had used PDF2JSON but we are getting json in format like this "Texts": [
          {
            "x": 15.948,
            "y": 4.557,
            "w": 75.66,
            "sw": 0.32553125,
            "clr": 0,
            "A": "left",
            "R": [
              {
                "T": "FORM%20NO.%2016",
                "S": -1,
                "TS": [
                  0,
                  16,
                  1,
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }, actual text is in 'T'

Comment: Check with the node module readme file. There it is given how to get values from above output

Comment: Here x and y are coordinates of the field. In the above output, you posted, the fetched value is FORM 20NO 2016. So you need to fetch the value of key T

Comment: You need to fetch value of key R and then value of key T

Answer (score 0):

Simply what you need is to render a PDF in your application.
You could use this library [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer)

Almost all the basic functionalities are available as properties to this component. You could manipulate it to your requirement.

Comment: It is just displaying the PDF. I should fetch the details from PDF and store it in my database.